# How to parse long value to date in Python

Tags: python

I have this value returned from server 1394369201000 and I have to convert it to GWT date format?
I have found different ways in documentation to fix this:

```
dt = datetime.datestr(1394369201000 , 'yyyymmdd')
```

but this didn't work.

Could you please, help me to fix this?

Comment: And how is that value to be intepreted? Is it seconds since the UNIX epoch?

Comment: That's milliseconds since the epoch for `datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 9, 12, 46, 41)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1394369201000/1000.0)
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 9, 12, 46, 41)
```

Comment: This is more suitable approach for my case. My time is in milliseconds as you said guys. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your time is perhaps in milliseconds, use `time` module:

```
In [33]: import time

In [34]: time.gmtime(1394369201000/1000.)
Out[34]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=12, tm_min=46, tm_sec=41, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=68, tm_isdst=0)
```